# Xaml file in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, workflow-foundation-4

Actually i m trying to do something which actually i m not sure that is possible. I have a workflow service and i'm trying to make a Client application using ASP.NET
Is it possible to make a client workflow (.xaml) which is uses some custom activities of the workflow service inside the ASP.NET project?

Comment: BTW, "ASP.NET" is one word, with no spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a blog post that explains exactly what you need to do here [How to consume a WCF Service from a WF4 Workflow](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rjacobs/archive/2010/12/08/how-to-consume-a-wcf-service-from-a-wf4-workflow.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you are asking but if it is if you can host a workflow service in an ASP.NET application then yes you can.

Comment: hm ok. i am a beginner on workflow foundation. Ok i have a solution which contains a WCF workflow service application with some custom activities in it. If i make a new Workflow console application and i add a service reference to this wcf service then automatically those custom activities appears in my toolbox. But if i make an ASP. Net application and import in it a xaml file and then add a reference to this wcf service then the custom activities do not appear in my toolbox. Do you know y ?. Thx for your time